# Is the Sql Azure Dac Import/Export service WCF or REST or something else?

Tags: import, wcf-client, azure-sql-database, wcf-rest, dac

I downloaded the example application and was surprised to see quite complex web request building and handling.
Unfortunately I have not been able to find even one scrap of documentation about the service.

I tried using AddServiceReference in VS and svcutil.exe on the end points (both the http general one and the https region specific ones) which I found in the example project (again I couldn't find them listed anywhere on the web) and both seamed to find a wsdl of sorts which they both used to create wrapper classes. But neither one created an app.config

and no mater what kind of binding I set up for them, I can not get the client to communicate.

Is there any documentation for the service?
Is there a way to use it with WCF?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabbi,

i have the same thing here, there are some non MS sites discussing this:
- http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/05/export-and-back-up-your-sql-azure.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287597/Sql-Azure-Import-Export-Service-bacpac-dac-Extract

There is also a DacSample site, but that doc is bit messed up, mixing the DAC client tools with the hosted solution. if i read the doc correctly and follow the links i end up going in circles. Not funny :)

Good luck!
Pete

Comment: I love how you put a link to my article as an answer to me. :)